# Problems obfuscating Executable Jar with ProGuard

Tags: proguard

I have just created an Executable Jar of my application using Eclipse. I always try to help you to answer, but this time i really don't know what's going on.
In this project i've added some external class (org.java_websocket) and the conj Jar, used for mysql connections.
In the link below i get like 800+ rows of warnings, but problems are just a few.
To obfuscate this project, i'm using Proguard GUI. I have unchecked shrinking and Optimization, and i've kept the main class of my application inserting it in the bottom box of obfuscation window (i have inserted "SimulatorServer").

That's the Proguard Output after processing is done. I don't get any Jar on output
http://pastebin.com/q2c4KUnq

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep that external JARs from being obfuscation.
You can get general information for ProGuardGUI [here](http://karnshah8890.blogspot.in/2014/03/mastering-proguard-with-proguard-gui.html)